# Single metric that evaluates how much the data is correlative

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, correlation, pearson-r

I want to calculate a single metric that evaluates how much the data is correlative.
For example, I thought about averaging the absolute values of the correlation matrix.
Is there a known metric for that goal?

Comment: Not knowing more about the problem you want to solve, mean correlation magnitude sounds like a fine way to do this (probably want the mean and not the sum, so you do not get large numbers just because you have many variables). Is there something about it that does not satisfy your needs? // This is screaming “XY problem” to me, where you have problem X and want to solve it with solution Y (overall correlation), but you also have a question about Y, so you ask about Y instead of X. Do you have some issue X?